# Как открыть файл с базой данных , закрытой паролем

Tags: java, c#, android, sqlite

есть файл который содержит базу данных- он создаётся кодом с#, но есть загвоздка в том, что он с паролем. Вот строка подключения от автора проги , создающей файл:

```
string constr = String.Format("Data Source = {0};FailIfMissing = false;Read Only = false;Password = {1}", path, pass);
connect = new SQLiteConnection(constr);
```

используя либы :

```
System.Data.SQLite.dll и SQLite.Interop.dll
```

Каким способом можно открыть на java Андройд? 
и заодно закрыть его тоже)

p.s.

Пытались через chiper , но ничего не вышло:

```
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.content.Context;

public class SqlChiperAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;


    public SqlChiperAdapter(Context ct, String patch, String name, String Secret)
    {
        super(ct,"Dgfgg",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(ct);

        sqLiteDatabase= SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(patch+name,Secret,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

И что получили:

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;
```

Comment: @tym32167  поправил эту странную ошибку

Comment: У меня есть проект использующий эту же библиотеку, сделал открытие базы как у вас - все работает. Перепроверьте очень внимательно путь до файла и ключ передаваемый. Попробуйте зашифровать азу ругим инструментом. Я шифровал этим браузером: https://sqlitebrowser.org

Comment: @Спицко дык, файл, расположенный в той же папке и являющейся бд , созданной на андройд-робит. Тут проблемма в том, что файл бд закрывается c# и то что chiper его открыть не может(

Comment: А какой ключ вы используете? Если вы используете поток чисел(rawkey), то могут быть проблемы с его переводом Java. И у вас не подходит просто пароль. Проверьте все же браузером, который я выше дал

Comment: @Спицко ключ - это просто строка с набором букв и чисел. SqliteBrowser в чистой сборке или с Chiper?

Comment: https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/ не вижу там упоминания чипера...

Comment: @Спицко я установил SqliteBrowser и он поставился мне чистый и chiper. Каким вы закрываете бд?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95758/discussion-between---and-deadmyself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, chiper просто берет файл БД и шифрует с помощью AES 256. Раз не удается открыть зашифрованную бд c chiper в андроиде и десктопном браузере бд, значит как-то отличаются методы шифрования. Может ключи разной длинны генерируются, может из-за вектора инициализации какие-то различия возникают... Варианты решения:

1. избавиться от шифрования, если это позволительно
2. использовать "прослойку" - некоторый сервер, который будет забирать у основного сервера бд в незашифрованном виде, шифровать понятным чиперу образом и отдавать клиенту
3. Разобраться с отличиями в шифровании, используемым библиотеками .Net, и шифрованием в чиппере. Если проблема, например, в векторе инициализации, то ее можно порешать программно